# Printing Dictionary in Vertical, and nested List in Horizontal

Tags: python, printing

How can I display the list (nested inside a dictionary) horizontally while still keeping the indentation? if I use `print()` only, the indentation is missing.

[image]

Tried below code, however the indentation is missing.

```
for key, value in new_pd_dict.items():
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

[image]

Comment: Suggestion: Read the value for of the key and print the key. If need formatting you might need to scan the value list. How about doing a `print(str(test_dict))`

Comment: how about something like this. `pprint.pprint(str(test['a']))`

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by indentation?

Comment: Hi It is solved. Thanks! The answer is what i mean by indentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to pass an argument to `pprint`, like `compact=True`.
From the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html#pprint.PrettyPrinter), "if compact is true, as many items as will fit within the width will be formatted on each output line"

```py
>>> pprint.pprint(new_pd_dict, compact=True)
{'Attack': [41, 87, 9, 38, 35, 30, 59, 98, 44, 9, 97, 53, 10, 79, 97, 46, 59,
            82, 75, 13, 72, 51, 80, 75, 80, 94, 88, 36, 76, 3, 32, 85, 95, 74,
            22, 28, 71, 57, 94, 29, 81, 89, 80, 42, 55, 7, 69, 3, 46, 40, 73,
            76, 41, 14, 47, 31, 45, 5, 78, 59, 4, 44, 4, 73, 9, 76, 60, 60, 16,
            2, 85, 6, 28, 21, 98, 1, 54, 24, 5, 1, 61, 39, 58, 26, 67, 52, 34,
            46, 23, 68, 25, 63, 36, 49, 66, 24, 2, 39, 15, 12]}
```

You can also adjust the width (defaults to 80) with `width=<number>` in function call.

Answer (score 0):

There is no in-built python library that does this. But you can just do:

```
my_dict = {"x": [1, 2, 3],
           "y": [4, 5, 6],
           "z": [7, 8, 9]}

for key, value in my_dict.items():
    print("%s: %s" % (key, value))
```

This short piece of code will yield something like this in the console:

```
y: [4, 5, 6]
x: [1, 2, 3]
z: [7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response but the indentation is missing, i have updated my question

Comment: @josephgan Be advised that the word wrapping mechanism is a feature of notebooks - and not necessarily due to the code you are writing.